# Searching array to print correct statement

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, cout

This code is for a game where the user inputs the size of a grid, which is filled with 0's except 1's in the first row. The user then enters coordinates, one at a time (same amount as size). If there is a 1 in the coordinate or in the 8 spaces surrounding it, then the 1 turns to a 0. If it wasn't hit, the 1 moves one row down. The other coordinate is tried, and so on. If at the end of the game, there are no 1's, the "stormtroopers" win. However, if at least 1 reaches the last row, the "redshirts" win. Basically, if all the coordinates are taken in and any 1's remain, the redshirts in. My problem is in determining who wins. My last statements are not working correctly; My program always says stormtroopers win and I've tried so many things, I don't know how to get it to work (lines 107-119). The for statements there might not be needed, I just tried them to see if they would fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ** createField(int N);
int playGame(int ** arr, int N);

int main()
{
    int N;

    cout << "Enter the number of Redshirts: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    int ** arr = createField(N);
    **createField(N);

    playGame(arr, N);
}

int ** createField(int N)
{
    int ** arr = new int *[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[N];            //creating array of user size

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)           // fills array with 0's except for first row
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
            arr[1][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

int playGame(int ** arr, int N)    
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "Enter the coordinates of the " << N << " shots: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> x >> y;
        x = x - 1;                                  // starts grid at 1 vs 0
        y = y - 1;
        if (x >= N || y >= N)
        {
            cout << "The coordinate is out of bounds." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[x][y] == 1)                     // searches each position for a redshirt (1)
                arr[x][y] = 0;
            if ((x + 1) != N)                       // these if statements check that surrounding spaces are not out of bounds
            {
                if (arr[x + 1][y] == 1)
                    arr[x + 1][y] = 0;
            }
            if ((x - 1) >= 0)
            {
                if (arr[x - 1][y] == 1)
                    arr[x - 1][y] = 0;
            }
            if ((y + 1) != N)
            {
                if (arr[x][y + 1] == 1)
                    arr[x][y + 1] = 0;
            }
            if ((y - 1) >= 0)
            {
                if (arr[x][y - 1] == 1)
                    arr[x][y - 1] = 0;
            }
            if ((x - 1) >= 0 && (y - 1) >= 0)
            {
                if (arr[x - 1][y - 1] == 1)
                    arr[x - 1][y - 1] = 0;
            }
            if ((x - 1) >= 0 && (y + 1) != N)
            {
                if (arr[x - 1][y + 1] == 1)
                    arr[x - 1][y + 1] = 0;
            }
            if ((x + 1) != N && (y + 1) != N)
            {
                if (arr[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
                    arr[x + 1][y + 1] = 0;
            }
            if ((y - 1) >= 0 && (x + 1) != N)
            {
                if (arr[x + 1][y - 1] == 1)
                    arr[x + 1][y - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            {
                if (arr[x][y] == 1)            // searches for any redshirts left
                {
                    arr[x + 1][y] = 1;         // moves remaining reshirts down one space
                    arr[x][y] = 0;
                }
            }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
        {
            if (arr[x][y] == 1)                                    // if redshirts reached end, they win
            {
                cout << "Redshirts win. " << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Stormtroopers win." << endl;
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end of your PlayGame function, what happens is at arr[0][0], if it is 1, it says Redshirts win, otherwise Stormtroopers win, there is no chance for your code to check other grids. You should just move the Stormtrooper winning message outside of the nested for loop.

```
for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        if (arr[x][y] == 1) // if redshirts reached end, they win
        {
            cout << "Redshirts win. " << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
cout << "Stormtroopers win." << endl;
return 2;
```

Comment: thank you! also, would you happen to know how to print the coordinates where 1 was left? I don't know how to retrieve those specific arrays.

Comment: A few ways to do that, one way is just print out the entire array out, then you can see value at all the coordinates. Another way is before you says redshirts win, you can print out the corresponding x and y to see where you find your first 1

Comment: Printing the entire array should be a very standard stuff.
`for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x) { for (int y = 0; y < N; ++y) {cout << arr[x][y] << " ";} cout << endl;}`